# Tradução de flag "setada"

Tags: tradução, tradução-inglês

Em uma pesquisa na internet, os textos em português costumam se referir a uma *flag = true* como estando "setada", marcada, ativa, definida.

Qual seria a tradução correta para a frase: "when the flag is set...", seguindo rigorosamente a língua portuguesa e documentos oficiais em C++? Não gosto de nenhum dos termos acima citado pois:

- "setado" não existe em português;
- marcada é um termo que se usa em elementos de GUI, por exemplo caixa
  de seleção;
- ativa a flag está, pois estamos testando o estado dela, seja em
  "true" como em "false"
- definida a flag está, pois senão não a estaríamos usando no código
  fonte.

Então... qual é a tradução correta **respeitando a língua portuguesa** para o estado da variável "flag"?

A mesma pergunta pode ser estendida ao termo "flag". Mas estou interessado na tradução do *estado* da "flag".

Comment: Entendo que a frase quer dizer que a _flag_ foi colocada no código ou definida.

Comment: Eu traduziria para flag como marcador e setado para definido. Então ficaria: "quando o marcador é (está) definido como verdadeiro..."

Answer (score 1):

Flag, literalmente, é bandeira. Usa-se essa palavra porque bandeiras sinalizam coisas. Flag, nesse contexto, serve para sinalizar coisas. Flags de processadores, por exemplo, sinalizam detalhes de operações, como "houve overflow na última operação?", sendo assim acho que a tradução mais adequada para a palavra flag é sinal ou sinalização.

Comment: _Flag_ também serve como verbo _indicar_; nesse sentido, a substantivação desse _flag_ é interpretada como _indicador_. Tá, com liberdade poética _bandeira_ e _indicador_ são palavras intercambiáveis

Answer (score 1):

A flag funciona como uma **sinalização** a respeito de determinada condição que possa ser respondida atraves de um simples true/false (1/0).

Exemplos:

- 'Status
- 'Deseja receber email?'
- 'É estudante?'
- 'Possui alguma deficiência?'